# Reversible hash function (?)

Tags: algorithms

I am looking at a problem where I have an assembly/collection of items, `V`, and my goal is to issue an `ID` to this collection, such that:

1. this `ID` uniquely identifies `V`, aka a change in `V` results in a change in the `ID` of
   `V` (much like a hash function),
2. given `V`, I can generate the `ID` and,
3. given the `ID` I can work out which items are in the collection (what the corresponding `V` looks like)

Is there a good way to do this apart from the obvious one<sup>1</sup>? Am I practically looking for a reversible hash function?

<sup>*1. by obvious I mean like an enumeration of sorts, not sure what it is formally called; like a 1 in the thousands means X, a 2 means Y and so on*</sup>

---

**Example**

Imaging running a supermarket and wanting to assign an `ID` to the receipts (`V`) you issue based on the items that were purchased. Your input is a collection of serial numbers that represent the purchased products. This `ID` is generated at check-out and printed on the receipt. The customer could then, by providing only this one `ID` communicate to you the entire list of purchased items since you can then decode the `ID` they provided.

*This is just a silly example aimed at helping you understand my end goal and has nothing to do with the application I am working on*

Comment: A hash function by definition, isn't reversible. If you use a reversible function, then it isn't a hash function. What you need is a way to encode your collection in an ID.

Comment: @RinkeshP I see, this is also more or less what is mentioned [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63052/reversible-hash-function). As far as the encoding goes, are there any good practices around?

Comment: Depends on the use case, and also if it is worth the effort to come up with such an encoding and extracting information from it, when there are other standard approaches to do so. But if you insist, you can just put all relevant information(like name, attributes, count etc) in a string.

Comment: Define what you mean by "good way".  Right now the question seems subjective and not answerable, because you haven't given any evaluation metrics or criteria for how you will evaluate "good" or how others should evaluate proposed answers.

Comment: @D.W. Thats a fair point but at this early stage I am interested in any working solution.

Comment: Your question might not be suitable for this site's format, then.  You already have one working solution (which you call "the obvious one").  Questions that ask to brainstorm more examples, without criteria, aren't a good fit for our format.

Answer (score 1):

There are three interesting cases:

- The keys to be stored in the hash table are known in advance. In this case, it is possible to construct a hash function that is injective over the set of stored keys; this is, essentially, [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). Perfect hashing doesn't give you a direct way to reconstruct the key from the hash value, but at least it's possible in principle.
- The set of possible queries to be performed on the hash table is known in advance. This is, if you like, the converse of perfect hashing, but instead of building a hash function that is surjective over the *stored* keys, you build one that is surjective over the *queried* keys. I don't know if this has a standard name, but the ideas (and the construction algorithms) are the same.
- The set of all possible keys is finite and has the same (or lesser) cardinality as the codomain of the hash function. If it's the same, you can in principle construct a hash function that is *bijective*, or a permutation of the key space.

An important example of this third case is hashing fixed-length bit strings (e.g. integers, pointers, network addresses, fixed-length DNA sequences). What's interesting about this is that any cryptographic block cipher is a hash function! But even if you don't need cryptographic-level security, using a [Feistel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) is a popular choice for building hash functions of this type.

If the set of possible keys is unbounded (e.g. strings) but the set of possible hash values is not, then it's clearly not possible to have an invertible hash function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the interesting information provided. The items are in fact know in advance and their set is also finite. I think you lost me on your second case. What do you mean by queries?

Comment: The second case is where the items stored in the hash table may be unknown, but the questions you will ask (is X in the table?) are known.